# Calling an external function of nested function

Tags: javascript, oop

Goog day.

```
var obj = new Foo("start");   
Foo = function(some){

            this.first = function(){
                alert("First");
                $(".clazz").click($.proxy(this.second,this));
            };

            this.second = function(){
               $(".clazz").append("<span>Second</span>");
               //this.out() // Problemb with called a method "this.out()"
            };

            this.out = function(){
                $(".clazz").append("<a>Out</a>");
                // Code
            };

            this.constructor = function(some){
                this.first();
            };
            this.constructor(some);
        };
```

How to call a method "this.out" from the method "this.second" ?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sombik/3PnA9/4/)

Comment: That code doesn't make sense. Are you trying to come up with new patterns?

Comment: First, you have several errors in your code `var Foo = new function() {}:` maybe you should something like this... `function Foo() { /*some code */ }` use function declaration instead of expression and create new variable... like this `var foo = new Foo();` and then `foo.out();`

Comment: Did you _try_ `this.out`?

Comment: @Givi: This is not an error, but it is useless.

Comment: You call it with `this.out()`, assuming you are calling `this.second` (and `this.first`) properly. Please show us what you are actually doing with `Foo`.

Comment: @FelixKling Yes, you're right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One common pattern is to explicitly declare a local variable containing a reference to the object.  This is usually called either `self` or `_this`.  The benefit is that no matter what other code does, your function will always be bound to your object.  In the below example, we see that `this.prop` isn't always bound correctly.  However, by only using `self` to refer to the object, we can avoid all issues surrounding this.

JavaScript libraries often use `apply` or `call` in a way that binds our functions in ways we don't desire.

```
function Foo(arg1){
    var self = this;
    self.prop = arg1;

    self.first = function(){
    };

    self.second = function(){
       alert("this.prop = " + this.out() + "\n" + // 2 (baz.prop)
             "self.prop = " + self.out() + "\n"); // 1 (bar.prop)
    };

    self.out = function(){
           return this.prop; // Depends on the context, we should use self.prop
    };
}

var bar = new Foo(1);
var baz = new Foo(2);
bar.second.apply(baz);
```

### Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WduGv/)